# which is one better code for goroutine overhead

Tags: go, overhead, goroutine

I want to make Reader.Read concurrent with channel communication.
so I made two ways to run it

1:

```
type ReturnRead struct {
    n   int
    err error
}

type ReadGoSt struct {
    Returnc <-chan ReturnRead
    Nextc chan struct{}
}

func (st *ReadGoSt) Close() {
    defer func() {
        recover()
    }()
    close(st.Next)
}

func ReadGo(r io.Reader, b []byte) *ReadGoSt {
    returnc := make(chan ReturnRead)
    nextc := make(chan bool)

    go func() {
        for range nextc {
            n, err := r.Read(b)
            returnc <- ReturnRead{n, err}
            if err != nil {
                return
            }
        }
    }()

    return &ReadGoSt{returnc, nextc}
}
```

2:

```
func ReadGo(r io.Reader, b []byte) <-chan ReturnRead {
    returnc := make(chan ReturnRead)
    go func() {
        n, err := r.Read(b)
        returnc <- ReturnRead{n, err}
    }()
    return returnc
}
```

i think code 2 creates too many overhead

which is the better code? 1? 2?

Answer (score 1):

Code 1 is better and probably faster. Code 2 will just read once. But I think both solutions are not the best. you should loop over the read and send back only the bytes readed.

Something like : http://play.golang.org/p/zRPXOtdgWD